# Ability to connect multiple models in MainModule (ScopedModel) using Flutter and dart language

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am connecting all `ScopeModel` classes in one `MainModel` classes with the help of "mix in". In Scope_model project I have 2 class (`ProductModel` and `UserModel` ) every extends `Model`.

When I merge all these 2 classes in the `MainModel` class it shows the error saying that it extends a class other than object.

When I remove `Model` class extends with `ProductModel` and `UserModel` then the error didn't happen anymore. But I was unable to use `notifylistner` property in that code.

I want to remove error mixin extends a class other then object without removing extends of `Model` class with `ProductModel` and `UserModel`

```
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart'; 
import '../models/product.dart';

class ProductsModel extends Model  {
  List<Product> _products = [];
  int _selectedProductIndex;
  bool _showFavorites = false;

  List<Product> get products {
    return List.from(_products);
  } 

 void addProduct(Product product) {
    _products.add(product);
    _selectedProductIndex = null;
   notifyListeners();
  }
```

```
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import '../models/user.dart';

class UserModel  extends Model {
  User _authenticatedUser;

  void login(String email, String password) {
    _authenticatedUser = User(id: 'fdalsdfasf', email: email, password: password);
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

import './products.dart';
import './user.dart';

class MainModel extends Model with UserModel, ProductsModel {}
```

Comment: How is this related to JavaScript and Java? Any reason you did not use `flutter` and `dart` as label?

Comment: "shows the error saying" If your question is about an error message you get make sure you post the full and exact error message, otherwise posting the question is mostly a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Here's what I found out on [Medium](https://medium.com/@amandeepkochhar/flutter-dart-the-class-cant-be-used-as-a-mixin-because-it-extends-a-class-other-than-object-a53eb5f214b0).

1. In the pubspec.yaml file, at the very end paste these lines

   ```
   analyzer:
       strong-mode: true
       language:
         enableSuperMixins: true
   ```

*Make sure to indent them properly.*

2. In the same directory as the pubspec.yaml file, make a file named *analysis_options.yaml* and paste the following code in

   ```
   analyzer:
       errors: 
       mixin_inherits_from_not_object: ignore
   ```